# Pyspark - Get all parameters of models created with ParamGridBuilder

Tags: python, machine-learning, pyspark, apache-spark-ml, hyperparameters

I'm using PySpark 2.0 for a Kaggle competition. I'd like to know the behavior of a model (`RandomForest`) depending on different parameters. `ParamGridBuilder()` allows to specify different values for a single parameters, and then perform (I guess) a Cartesian product of the entire set of parameters. Assuming my `DataFrame` is already defined:

```
rdc = RandomForestClassifier()
pipeline = Pipeline(stages=STAGES + [rdc])
paramGrid = ParamGridBuilder().addGrid(rdc.maxDepth, [3, 10, 20])
                              .addGrid(rdc.minInfoGain, [0.01, 0.001])
                              .addGrid(rdc.numTrees, [5, 10, 20, 30])
                              .build()
evaluator = MulticlassClassificationEvaluator()
valid = TrainValidationSplit(estimator=pipeline,
                             estimatorParamMaps=paramGrid,
                             evaluator=evaluator,
                             trainRatio=0.50)
model = valid.fit(df)
result = model.bestModel.transform(df)
```

OK so now I'm able to retrieves simple information with a handmade function:

```
def evaluate(result):
    predictionAndLabels = result.select("prediction", "label")
    metrics = ["f1","weightedPrecision","weightedRecall","accuracy"]
    for m in metrics:
        evaluator = MulticlassClassificationEvaluator(metricName=m)
        print(str(m) + ": " + str(evaluator.evaluate(predictionAndLabels)))
```

Now I want several things:

- What are the parameters of the best model? This post partially answers the question: [How to extract model hyper-parameters from spark.ml in PySpark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36697304/how-to-extract-model-hyper-parameters-from-spark-ml-in-pyspark)
- What are the parameters of all models?
- What are the results (aka recall, accuracy, etc...) of each model ? I only found `print(model.validationMetrics)` that displays (it seems) a list containing the accuracy of each model, but I can't get to know which model to refers.

If I can retrieve all those informations, I should be able to display graphs, bar charts, and work as I do with Panda and `sklearn`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Spark 2.4+**

[SPARK-21088](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-21088) *CrossValidator, TrainValidationSplit should collect all models when fitting* - adds support for collecting submodels.

By default this behavior is disabled, but can be controlled using `CollectSubModels` `Param` (`setCollectSubModels`).

```
valid = TrainValidationSplit(
    estimator=pipeline,
    estimatorParamMaps=paramGrid,
    evaluator=evaluator,            
    collectSubModels=True)

model = valid.fit(df)

model.subModels
```

**Spark < 2.4**

Long story short you simply cannot get parameters for all models because, [similarly to `CrossValidator`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38874828/1560062), `TrainValidationSplitModel` retains only the best model. These classes are designed for semi-automated model selection not exploration or experiments.

> What are the parameters of all models?

While you cannot retrieve actual models `validationMetrics` correspond to input `Params` so you should be able to simply `zip` both:

```
from typing import Dict, Tuple, List, Any
from pyspark.ml.param import Param
from pyspark.ml.tuning import TrainValidationSplitModel

EvalParam = List[Tuple[float, Dict[Param, Any]]]

def get_metrics_and_params(model: TrainValidationSplitModel) -> EvalParam:
    return list(zip(model.validationMetrics, model.getEstimatorParamMaps()))
```

to get some about relationship between metrics and parameters.

If you need more information you should use [Pipeline `Params`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35253990/1560062). It will preserve all model which can be used for further processing:

```
models = pipeline.fit(df, params=paramGrid)
```

It will generate a list of the `PipelineModels` corresponding to the `params` argument:

```
zip(models, params)
```

Comment: Thank you, I can now get evaluation metrics for each model. Unfortunately, ``zip(model.validationMetrics, model.getEstimatorParamMaps())
`` does not work with models. When I print the model.params, it shows nothing (and my paramGrid works I am sure)

Comment: Yeah, this suggestion was only about `TrainValidationSplitModel`. I added typed hints to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found a way to do this. I wrote a function that specifically pulls out hyperparameters for a logistic regression that has two parameters, created with a CrossValidator:

```
def hyperparameter_getter(model_obj,cv_fold = 5.0):

    enet_list = []
    reg_list  = []

    ## Get metrics

    metrics = model_obj.avgMetrics
    assert type(metrics) is list
    assert len(metrics) > 0

    ## Get the paramMap element

    for x in range(len(model_obj._paramMap.keys())):
    if model_obj._paramMap.keys()[x].name=='estimatorParamMaps':
        param_map_key = model_obj._paramMap.keys()[x]

    params = model_obj._paramMap[param_map_key]

    for i in range(len(params)):
    for k in params[i].keys():
        if k.name =='elasticNetParam':
        enet_list.append(params[i][k])
        if k.name =='regParam':
        reg_list.append(params[i][k])

    results_df =  pd.DataFrame({'metrics':metrics, 
             'elasticNetParam': enet_list, 
             'regParam':reg_list})

    # Because of [SPARK-16831][PYTHON] 
    # It only sums across folds, doesn't average
    spark_version = [int(x) for x in sc.version.split('.')]

    if spark_version[0] <= 2:
    if spark_version[1] < 1:
        results_df.metrics = 1.0*results_df['metrics'] / cv_fold

    return results_df
```

Comment: This seems unnecessarily complex, is it really the best way?