# How to extract best parameters from a crossvalidator in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, scikit-learn, cross-validation

I have a question regarding extracting the hyperparameters from crossvalidator in PySpark. I have tried every single solution in stackoverflow and none of them work for me. I am not sure either those answers are old or I am making mistake somewhere.

I can perform distributed training and prediction successfully with SparkXGBRegressor, I can do cross validation using:

```
 crossval = CrossValidator(estimator=estimator,
                                     estimatorParamMaps=parm_grid,
                                     evaluator=evaluator,
                                     numFolds=numFolds,
                                     parallelism = parallelism)
  cv_model = crossval.fit(data)
```

The Param_grid is

```
param_grid = ParamGridBuilder()\
        .addGrid(estimator.n_estimators, [100, 200]) \
        .addGrid(estimator.max_depth, [4,6])\
        .build()
```

However after training I want to get the best hyperparameters and I am not sure how to do that since:= this is not working:

```
cv_model.bestModel
```

and returns something like this
`

```
SparkXGBRegressor_7651797ba9ba
```

`
Which does not make any sense. Can anyone explain how to return the best hyperparameters similar to Python which is like

```
cv_model.best_params_
```

I am sure there is a way to do this.

I have looked at answers such as

[How to extract model hyper-parameters from spark.ml in PySpark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36697304/how-to-extract-model-hyper-parameters-from-spark-ml-in-pyspark)

[Pyspark - Get all parameters of models created with ParamGridBuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39529012/pyspark-get-all-parameters-of-models-created-with-paramgridbuilder)

[How to extract best parameters from a CrossValidatorModel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31749593/how-to-extract-best-parameters-from-a-crossvalidatormodel)

None worked for me. I would appreciate if anyone can help me here.